# How to have the ANT video downloader extension work on newest ubuntu+firefox

Tags: firefox, video

I have been using the ANT video downloader extension in firefox since years. I just installed ubuntu mate 18.04 with latest firefox and after installing the extension I am asked to install a native app that is a .msi file and can't be open in ubuntu with any program. Any solutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned on their [*website*](https://www.ant.com/video-downloader), the current version extension (3.x for FF57 and later) only supports Windows (the reason for the .msi file). A Linux release is planned but not yet.

To use on Linux, you need to use the old extension version 2.x and FF56 or lower. I use FF52esr to keep up on security updates.

Some additional explanation is here - [ABOUT THE NEW ANT VIDEO DOWNLOADER 3.0](https://support.ant.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005568983-ABOUT-THE-NEW-ANT-VIDEO-DOWNLOADER-3-0) .

Previous versions of the extension are here: [*Ant Video Downloader Version History*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloader-player/versions/).

Comment: Ok, I can understand that but how can I install the older versions? Which commands do I need to put into the terminal? Thank you for helping me out because it is so complicated for me....

Comment: I added a link to the previous versions. Install the same as other add-ons.